# How to Handle CommunicationException When Using Lists.asmx in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I get listitem data by using Lists.asmx in SharePoint 2010 (Form Authentication).

The code is like this.

```
private void GetItems(string listname)
{
    ListsService.ListsSoapClient client = new ListsService.ListsSoapClient();
    appset = new AppSettings();
    client.CookieContainer = appset.CookieSetting;
    client.GetListItemsAsync(listname, null, null, null, "10", null, null);

    client.GetListItemsCompleted += new EventHandler<ListsService.GetListItemsCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetListItemsCompleted);

}

void client_GetListItemsCompleted(object sender, ListsService.GetListItemsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.ItemsSource = from element in e.Result.Descendants(XName.Get("row", "#RowsetSchema"))
                            select new Lists
                            {
                                Title = (string)element.Attribute("ows_LinkTitle")
                            };
}
```

When the timeout of form authentication is occurred, unhandled CommunicationException is raised. The stack trace is here.

at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException, HttpChannelFactory factory)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.ProcessResponse(HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.OnGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClassa.b*_8(Object state2)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
   at System.Threading.Timer.ring()

I couldn't handle CommunicationException even if I use try~catch.
So, please let me know how to handle CommunicationException.

Answer (score 0):

You should register for the GetListItemsCompleted event before calling GetListItemsAsync. Also, wrap GetListItemsAsync in a try-catch block.

Any error will be thrown as an exception from the call to GetListItemsAsync or will be reported as an error through GetListItemsCompletedEventArgs.

Comment: Thanks your advice. But I couldn't resolve using your advice. It seems that CommunicationException is occurred before GetListItemsCompleted is kicked. Also I couldn't catch the Exception in a try~catch block.